# How to read a latex table with pgfplotstableread with \begin{table} \etc

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I would like to read data from a `.tex` file using `\pgfplotstableread`. The `.tex` file contains table with `\begin` etc. tags and I am asking for a clean way to strip this. I can skip the first lines but not the last line.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{data.tex}
  1 & 2\\
  3 & 4\\
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datatable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{|r|r|}\hline
 a & b\hline
\endhead
  1 & 2\\
  3 & 4\\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

Works:
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&,header=false]{data.tex}{\data}

Doesn't work:
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&,header=false, skip first n={3}]{datatable.tex}{\datatwo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that reading `data.tex` works? You will have `\\ ` as part of the second data item; is this intended? `\pgfplotstableread` is used to read csv-data, not LaTeX tables.

Comment: Yes it works for me, I think you can tell it that lines end with `\\ ` but I didn't need to in my examples (I didn't use the last column). I think it is even in the docs. Alternatively, I could read the file line by and only keep lines starting with a number and pass it to pgfplotstableread. Or is there a package reading the values from a LaTeX table, I am not aware of? I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that one can declare `\\ ` as row separator. Sorry, no idea how to skip the last line directly. I'd filter the tex file with a script before feeding it to `\pgfplotstableread`. Alternatively, you could read the table as a single column and then filter the rows in LaTeX. `pgfplots` allows to skip rows by index (`/pgfplots/table/skip rows between index={begin}{end}`, see `pgfplotstable` manual), but then you have to split the rows afterwards.

Comment: Okay, I got something working since the data is numerical by ignoring `\ ` and making `e` a comment character.

Comment: @gernot, that is also a nice idea! Have read it wrong the first time.